# I can't click my link in my unordered list

Tags: html, css, list, hyperlink

Can someone help me, I can't see where's the problem in my code. I can't click my links. When I enabled the link decoration it has an underline that shows it's a link, but I can't click it. Looking forward to solve my problem, thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="chapter-number">
          
        <ul class="ul-chapter">
            <li><a href="matthew-1.html">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="ul-chapter">
            <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="ul-chapter">
            <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="ul-chapter">
            <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">18</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">19</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="ul-chapter">
            <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">25</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="ul-chapter">
            <li><a href="#">26</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">27</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">28</a></li>
            
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chapter-number {
  font-family: gotham;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ul-chapter li {
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline;
}

.ul-chapter {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`:

```css
.ul-chapter li {
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ul-chapter {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-chapter">
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-chapter">
  <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-chapter">
  <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">18</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">19</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-chapter">
  <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">25</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-chapter">
  <li><a href="#">26</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">27</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">28</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. Huhu